# WCF and custom fault?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, fault

I am trying centralize the Exception handling in my WCF service by using a  `ErrorHandler`(`System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler`)

This is how the ProvideFault look like :

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {

        if (error is ValidationHandler)
        {
            var val = error as ValidationHandler;
            var val2 = ErrorHandler.HandleException(val);
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, val2.CreateMessageFault(), "http://ns");
        }
        else if (error is FaultException)
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, (error as FaultException).CreateMessageFault(), "http://ns");
        else
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, ErrorHandler.HandleException(error).CreateMessageFault(), "http://ns");
    }
```

The `ValidationHandler` is a `System.Exception` but do not have `datacontract` attribute. `ValidationHandler` contains a list of `MainValidation` where all data is stored and this class is decorated with `datacontract` attribute.

`ErrorHandler.HandleException` will translate the `ValidationHandler` to a `FaultException<MyCustomFault>` that is a custom `FaultException` containing `ExceptionContainer`(`datacontract`) containing the list of `MainValidation`(`datacontract`).

If I remove the `IErrorHandler` and just throws the `ErrorHandler.HandleExceptio`n direcly from the service method everything works fine. The CustomFault as arriving at the client and the validation can be handled.

But while using `IErrorHandler` the fault that arrive at the client can´t be casted to a `FaultException<MyCustomFault>`? It seems like data is lost when running the `Message.CreateMessage`?

Edit 1 : I can see that the MessageFault that are generated from CreateMessageFault do have a detail and if I cast this to my MyCustomFault I can read the content properly. The question is why this is not included when arriving at the client?

Edit 2 : When the exception arrives at the client I try to cast it to FaultException but this returns null. So the MyCustomFault seems to be lost on the way?

Edit 3 : I have the following set on the behavior in the config :

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to change the "http://ns" to null(MyCustomFault.Action). Found it here : [WCF: provide generic FaultException in IErrorHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160426/wcf-provide-generic-faultexception-in-ierrorhandler)